# Executing Flashbuilder application results in Error 2148 Only local-with-filesystem and trusted local SWF files may access local resources

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

As the title implies i have problems making a very simple (actually an empty project) to run!

I always get the follwing error:

```
SecurityError: Error #2148: SWF file file:///C:/Users/Σάββας/Adobe Flash Builder 4/Test/bin-debug/Test.swf cannot access local resource file:///C:/Users/Σάββας/Adobe Flash Builder 4/Test/bin-debug/osmf_flex.4.0.0.13495.swf. Only local-with-filesystem and trusted local SWF files may access local resources.
    at flash.net::URLStream/load()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/load()
    at mx.core::CrossDomainRSLItem/load()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\CrossDomainRSLItem.as:240]
    at mx.core::RSLListLoader/loadNext()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\RSLListLoader.as:184]
    at mx.core::RSLListLoader/load()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\RSLListLoader.as:156]
    at mx.preloaders::Preloader/initialize()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\preloaders\Preloader.as:279]
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::initialize()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:1925]
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/initHandler()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2419]
```

Is there something i have done wrong? Ι also tried to debug (the empty application) with no success!!

I tried to set the Global Security Settings for the folders involved in developing to always allow but the result is the same!!

My problem is that i will not be able to debug the application which is of verrrryyyy annoying.

I 'm using Flashbuilder 4, FlexSDK4, Mozilla.

Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: [this might help](http://blog.mandalatv.net/2007/06/flex-securityerror-error-2148-while-accessing-local-xml/)

Comment: I've already tried this. I 've seen many people suggesting this as solution. I'm very new to this Flex/Flash stuff, but i 'm sure this is not a solution to my problem. The application i want to build has to download a SWF module from the web, so this approach is not feasible. Thanks for the try!

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when you try to open an application that uses RSLs in the standalone player or in the browser by using the file system and not a server. It means that you are violating the security sandbox of Flash Player by trying to load file resources.

You must deploy your application and RSLs to a network location, and request the application with a network request so that Flash Player will load the RSL.

If you are testing the application locally, you can add the directory to your Player trust file to avoid this error.

Comment: How can i add the directory to Flash Players trust file list? Is that done through the Global Security Settings? If so, i 've already done this with no success!

Comment: Just add the http://localhost URL to the trust list in the player - not the directory.

Comment: I think i understand. But what about debugging? Will debugging be possible?

Comment: If you are using the Flash Debug Player then you can debug in the player. If this is your Debug machine then just delete your regular Flash player and use the Debug one.

Comment: Adding the folder in Global Security Settings fixed it for me.